# How to save custom color on localStorage jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I` have a function in jquery witch allow users to change background color of site. But if they refresh the page background-color go to default. How can i use LocalStorage with this jquery function

```js
sessionStorage.setItem("bg_color", "#000");
let personName = sessionStorage.getItem("bg_color");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dark__mode').click(function() {
        $('#headerCustomColor').css("background-color", personName);
        $('#TogleBarWi').css("color", "#fff");
        $('.custom_color_link').css("color", "#fff");
    });
});
```

Comment: I see this. But dont know how to update to my code

Comment: As i can understand you already have a working code with localStorage.
Just replace the word localStorage into sessionStorage.

Comment: Think what you need example when your document is ready
`let background = `  try to get localStorage.getItem('background-color') ? if is true localStorage.getItem('background-color') : else "#default color

Than  you can set inside your `click()` event `localStorage.setItem("background-color", "#383838");

Comment: Okay . Now i can use session storage. But still when i refresh site, background change to default, dont keep color from sessionStorage

Comment: Share your current code

Comment: Just updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//You have to check if there is a certain background
// If there is a background color use it else use default
let background = localStorage.getItem("background") ? localStorage.getItem("background") : "#FFF";

// Change header on document loading the background color based on localStorage
$('#headerCustomColor').css("background-color", background);

// On click
$('.dark__mode').click(function() {
    // Set the variable background to custom
    background = "#383838";
    // Set localStorage bg color to custom 
    // This is to enable on refresh so the new bg is set.
    localStorage.setItem("background", background);
    
    // Recolor the header after the click
    $('#headerCustomColor').css("background-color", background);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! This was hlpfouly